# Is there an ant equivalent to make generic rules?

Tags: ant, makefile

Is there an Apache Ant equivalent to make rules of the form:

```
%.object: %.source
    ${TRANSFORMER} $< -o $@
```

This is a pattern that I find myself using frequently and really miss from make.  It would be even better if there is an equivalent that can detect changes to the source files similar to the way make does.

Comment: See the apply task: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html

Comment: That's close, it let's you run a process over a set of files ... but that's not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: Just remember, ANT is not make. The tools are quite different.